# Passing Parameters to <input> tag in JSP

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I am trying tp pass a parameter to the input tag of the HTML form in JSP. I have a table displaying patient records with an Edit button which redirects to the update.jsp page where the update form is displayed with all the initial values set to the ones in the original table. The most important piece of table in Patient.jsp file looks as follows:

```
    <c:forEach var="patients" items="${patients}">
        <tr>
            <td>${patients.getPatientId()}</td>
            <td>${patients.getPatientfName()}</td>
            <td>${patients.getPatientlName()}</td>
            <td>${patients.getPatientEmail()}</td>
            <td>${patients.getPatientPhone()}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href='update.jsp?u=${patients.getPatientId()}' class="btn">Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

In the update.jsp file I have a simple form (just showing 1 row for simplicity):

```
<form name="update" action="ProductDisplay" method="post">
    <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Patient ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="ID" value="${request.getParameter("u")}"></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Trying to set the value of the text field equal to the one in the original table. If I access it directly in update.jsp like so:

```
<%
    String str = request.getParameter("u");
    System.out.println(str);
%>
```

everything works fine, the value of the ID in the table is passed and printed. However, when I try to use it in the form (value="${request.getParameter("u")}") nothing happens, the field value remains blank. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should use  value='${param.u}' EL has implicit variables.

Comment: value='${param.u}'  also works, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. For those who may run into the same problem use:

```
<%
   String str = request.getParameter("u");
%>
```

And then in the tag:

```
value='<%=str%>'
```